# Generating new column of data by aggregating specific columns of dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset has a few interesting columns that I want to aggregate, and hence create a metric that I can use to do some more analysis.

The algorithm I wrote takes around ~3 seconds to finish, so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
def financial_score_calculation(df, dictionary_of_parameters):
    for parameter in dictionary_of_parameters:
        for i in dictionary_of_parameters[parameter]['target']:
            index = df.loc[df[parameter] == i].index
            for i in index:
                old_score = df.at[i, 'financialliteracyscore']
                new_score = old_score + dictionary_of_parameters[parameter]['score']
                df.at[i, 'financialliteracyscore'] = new_score
    for i in df.index:
        old_score = df.at[i, 'financialliteracyscore']
        new_score = (old_score/27.0)*100 #converting score to percent value
        df.at[i, 'financialliteracyscore'] = new_score

    return df
```

Here is a truncated version of the dictionary_of_parameters:

```
dictionary_of_parameters = {
    # money management parameters
    "SatisfactionLevelCurrentFinances": {'target': [8, 9, 10], 'score': 1},
    "WillingnessFinancialRisk": {'target': [8, 9, 10], 'score': 1},
    "ConfidenceLevelToEarn2000WithinMonth": {'target': [1], 'score': 1},
    "DegreeOfWorryAboutRetirement": {'target': [1], 'score': 1},
    "GoodWithYourMoney?": {'target': [7], 'score': 1}
    }
```

EDIT: generating toy data for df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = dictionary_of_parameters.keys())
df['financialliteracyscore'] = 0
for i in range(10):
    df.loc[i] = dict(zip(df.columns,2*i*np.ones(6)))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a sample dataframe and dictionary of your parameters.  A minimum verifiable example.

Comment: A quick critique: Don't use the same loop index repeatedly (you are using ````i```` within another loop with ````i````). Yes, there's a faster way to do it with column operations rather than elementwise operations.

Comment: Is your ````dictionary_of_parameters```` a dictionary of dictionaries / dataframes? If you post a sample data it would make it a lot easier for us to help.

Comment: I edited the post just now to include a short version of `dictionary_of_parameters`. The dataframe is a bit large, but what I can tell you is that the key values of this dictionary represent the particular column names that I want to aggregate from the dataframe.  Sorry about that!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a test dataset that has the same columns and a few rows. I edited your question as an example to create a test dataset that makes it easy for other people to implement solutions on their own computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in Pandas you can index in ways other than elementwisely with `at`. In the four-liner below, `index` is a list which can then be used for indexing with `loc`.

```
for parameter in dictionary_of_parameters:
    index = df[df[parameter].isin(dictionary_of_parameters[parameter]['target'])].index
    df.loc[index,'financialliteracyscore'] += dictionary_of_parameters[parameter]['score']
df['financialliteracyscore'] = df['financialliteracyscore'] /27.0*100
```

Here's a reference although I personally never found it useful in my earlier days of programming... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html